# Multiple LIKE clauses SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a query to show patients who are on certain types of medication. I have a list of a few different meds that I'm seeking -- I am looking to see if there are any patients in the database who have a prescription for any of these medications that is end-dated on or after today's date.

The medications appear by name in a table, so I am trying to find them using `LIKE`. But once I add more than one med, my query blows up to pull a lot of duplicates (goes from 362 rows to over 32K rows returned), and ignores all the items in my `WHERE` clause after the meds.

So here's what I've tried:

```
    select p.PatientID, 
    p.FirstName+' '+p.LastName as 'PatientName', 
    m.endDate, 
    m.Prescriber, 
    m.drugDescription as 'DrugName'
    from Medications m
    join Patients p on p.RCDID = m.PTID
    where m.historyRecord = 'N'
    and m.[current] = 'Y'
    and m.drugDescription like 'Med1%'
    or m.drugDescription like 'Med2%'
    or m.drugDescription like 'Med3%'
    and m.endDate >= GETDATE()
```

This gives me over 30K duplicates -- and the repeating patient does not meet the following criteria in the `WHERE` clause:

```
    where m.historyRecord = 'N'
    and m.[current] = 'Y'        
    and m.endDate >= GETDATE()
```

(and this patient actually only appears in the database for 21 rows -- Med2 prescribed on 21 different times -- so it's completely gone off the rails)

I tried a subquery also:

```
    select p.PatientID, 
    p.FirstName+' '+p.LastName as 'PatientName', 
    m.endDate, 
    m.Prescriber, 
    m.drugDescription as 'DrugName'
    from Medications m
    join Patients p on p.RCDID = m.PTID
    where m.historyRecord = 'N'
    and m.[current] = 'Y'
    and exists (select 1 from Medications m1
                where m1.PTID = m.PTID
                and m1.drugDescription like 'Med1%'
                or m1.drugDescription like 'Med2%'
                or m1.drugDescription like 'Med3%'
                and m1.endDate >= GETDATE())
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
PatientID | PatientName | endDate   | Prescriber | DrugName
1         | John Smith  | 2017-10-22| Dr. Jones  | Med1
1         | John Smith  | 2017-10-22| Dr. Jones  | Med3
2         | Mary Doe    | 2017-11-01| Dr. Johnson| Med2
3         | Steve Doe   | 2017-11-15| Dr. Smith  | Med1
```

Any suggestions? I've done some digging and haven't quite hit on anything that has worked yet, so ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need parentheses!

```
where m.historyRecord = 'N' and
      m.[current] = 'Y' and
      m.endDate >= GETDATE() and
      (m.drugDescription like 'Med1%' or
       m.drugDescription like 'Med2%' or
       m.drugDescription like 'Med3%'
      )
```

If you are learning SQL, always use parentheses when mixing `and` and `or`.

Comment: Jesus christ, you caught that faster than speed of light

Comment: This returns 0 rows -- I know there are people who meet the m.drugDescription like 'Med1%' (approx 300) and are about 400 more who meet the or 'Med2%' -- it's when Med3 gets into it that everything goes nuts.

Comment: @jfe042, Gordon is right. Perhaps there's something else wrong with your query such as the other filters. I would go through line by line in the `WHERE` clause and comment out one at a time to see which one is causing you grief.

Comment: @jfe042 . . . Perhaps it was with the end date.  If you are using `or`, adding another condition should not cause the query to be empty.

Comment: Got it - I had been using a single patientID as a test, and didn't remove it. Working perfectly now -- thank you! Punctuation. It gets me EVERY TIME.

Comment: You could lose the parentheses and combine all three m.drugDescription predicates like so: m.drugDescription like 'Med[1-3]%'

Comment: @AlanBurstein . . . You could, if you really believed that the descriptions have those names.  I'm guessing the meds have some other name.